# Select some columns of two tables and FULL OUTER JOIN them

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables that have only `id` in common. I want to FULL OUTER JOIN them.

```
SELECT *
FROM message m
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT id, result, start, finish, message
   FROM  message_execution) ex ON ex.id = m.id
WHERE  m.id = '1626'
```

It seems that the above statement work. However, I need only a few columns of the first table, not all of them. I have tried to specify the columns' name, but it did not work.

How can I select the columns that I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `select *` - select the columns you want:

```
select m.col_1, m.col_2, 
       ex.*
from message m 
  full outer join (
    select id, result, start, finish, message
    from message_execution
  ) ex on ex.id = m.id
where m.id = 1626;
```

Or you can simplify that to:

```
select m.col_1, m.col_2, 
       ex.id, ex.result, ex.start, ex.finish, ex.message
from message m 
  full outer join message_execution ex on ex.id = m.id
where m.id = 1626;
```

If `id` is defined as a number, you shouldn't compare it to a string constant. `'1626'` is a string constant, `1626` is a number.

---

Note that you `where` condition on the `message` table essentially turns the full join into a **left** join, so the above is equivalent to:

```
select m.col_1, m.col_2, 
       ex.id, ex.result, ex.start, ex.finish, ex.message
from message m 
  left outer join message_execution ex on ex.id = m.id
where m.id = 1626;
```

Comment: It was my mistake. Id is a `bigint`. Thanks a lot